# Viewing NAT connections with nftables

Tags: nat, nftables

How to track nat outgoing connections with nftables.
Just need to look at nat stats, which output addresses used more or less.

```
root@nat-1:~# nft list table nat
table ip nat {
    chain post {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
            ip saddr 10.0.0.0/8 oif "bond0.926" snat to 19.246.159.1-19.246.159.7
    }

    chain pre {
            type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
    }
}
```

netstat-nat works with iptables but not with nftables anymore.

```
netstat-nat -S
Could not read info about connections from the kernel, make sure netfilter is enabled in kernel or by modules.
```

I can of course use tcpdump, but there should be some nicer utility ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*iptables* or *nftables* aren't doing NAT: *netfilter* does it. *iptables* and *nftables* are using hooks into *netfilter* to give some "orders" to create new NAT states. Once done, it's all handled directly by *netfilter* (that's why, for both *iptables* and *nftables*, only the first packet of a nat table/type is seen). So in the end the NAT state keeper is netfilter and its conntrack subsystem.

Now, `netstat-nat` uses the kernel provided file `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` to display conntrack informations. If this file is not available (eg: not having full root privileges, being run in a container not mapping this part of `/proc` etc.) you can get an error. I don't know why it's not, but anyway, here's the specific conntrack backend tool: [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack/conntrack.8) (from [conntrack-tools](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/)) which relies exclusively on the newer API ([netlink](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/netlink.7)) rather than `/proc`. From its manpage, the equivalent command (with a completely different output of course) would be:

```
conntrack -L -n
```

> **COMMANDS**
>   [...]
>   **-L --dump**
>       List connection tracking or expectation table
>   [...]
>   -E, --event
>       Display a real-time event log.
>   [...]
>
> **FILTER PARAMETERS**
>   [...]
>   **-n, --src-nat**
>       Filter source NAT connections.

You can even follow source NAT states in real-time using the event mode:

```
conntrack -E -n
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Thanks.